# Symfony - Retrieve current user from in a command file

Tags: php, symfony

I'am currently working on a very old Symfony 2.4 project.

I have created a CsvImportCommand file to create adding massive customers with a csv functionality.

I need to set the current logged-in user as the value of my column 'created_by', but i do not know how can i get this information.

I saw that i could get this information in the twig template with `app.user` or with `get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()` in a controller file.

But i really do not know how can i retrieve this information in a command file.

Remember, it is a Symfony 2.4 project.

below are my codes, it returns an error : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) (on my 2nd line)

```
class CsvImportCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    private $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    private $username = $user->getUsername();

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('csv:import')
            ->setDescription('Import users from CSV file')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $output->writeln('<comment>Start:' . $now->format('d-m-Y G:i:s') . '---</comment>');

        $this->import($input, $output);

        $now = new \DateTime();
        $output->writeln('<comment>End:' . $now->format('d-m-Y G:i:s') . '---</comment>');
    }

    protected function import(InputInterface $input, Outputinterface $output)
    {
        $data = $this->get($input, $output);

        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        $em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

        $size = count($data);
        $batchSize = 20;
        $i = 1;

        foreach($data as $row) {
            $person = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Person')->findOneBy(array('firstname'=>$row['firstname'], 'lastname'=>$row['lastname']));

            if(!$person){
                $person = new Person();
                $em->persist($person);
            }
            $person->setIsPrivate($row['is_private']);
            $person->setCivility($row['civility']);
            $person->setFirstName($row['firstname']);
            $person->setLastName($row['lastname']);
            $person->setPhoneHome($row['phone_home']);
            $person->setMobileHome($row['mobile_home']);
            $person->setEmailPro($row['email_pro']);
            $person->setEmailHome($row['email_home']);
            $person->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $person->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $person->setCreatedBy($username);

            if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();

                $now = new \DateTime();
                $output->writeln('of users imported... | ' . $now->format('d-m-Y G:i:s'));
            }

            $i++;
        }

        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer the question - __who__ is logged in user in command line mode?

Comment: I suppose you could add a --username parameter and, if you were feeling extremely ambitious, even add a --password parameter.

Comment: You have syntax errors (can't use `$this->get()` when initializing a property) and conceptual errors (logically there is no user logged in when executing  a command line application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding your error:**

you can't use $this in class variables. U have to assign $user in the __construct or u create set-Methods. Something like: setUser.

**Regarding security-bundle with commands:**

U can't use the security.context because u dont have a user in this section.
Maybe u can fake it, but this is not so good.

Comment: For the security-bundle part, that means i can never retrieve the current logged-in user ? Any suggestion ? because i need this information to set my 'created_by' column. Maybe by calling something external ?

Comment: it depends from where you start this command. However, commands are generally started via crons. How do you get that?
oh well, if you start it via crons there is only one user which you know. You can add it statically.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider adding a "user" to your system to represent automated tasks such as this. Then you can retrieve the automated user and use that as your createdBy user.